# Classification problem: Choosing medication to prevent side effects based on patient characteristics

Tags: python, classification, multiclass-classification

I need your help to solve a classification problem. Typically, we have independent variables and we try to predict a target variable. I have a different type of problem to solve.

In my case, let's take a simple example. Suppose I have a database with 6 variables: "white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender," "medication," and "side_effects."

"Medication" contains 0 and 1 for the type of medication, and "side_effects" contains 0 and 1 for no side effects or yes.

I would like to create a classification model that examines the patient's characteristics ("white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender") and provides the correct value of "medication" such that "side_effects" = 0.

I'm not sure if there are tools available for this kind of problem, and I haven't found much information online. ChatGPT hasn't been very helpful either.

The solution I've tried, though I'm not sure if it's valid, is as follows:

I divided my database into two parts: "side_effects" = 0 and "side_effects" = 1.
I created two random forest models to predict "medication."

The first model, where the database is "side_effects" = 0, predicts either medication 0 or 1. This would mean that this medication should be chosen to avoid side effects.
The second model, where the database is "side_effects" = 1, predicts either medication 0 or 1. This would imply that this medication causes side effects.

Then, I added the predict_proba from the first model to the smaller one from the second model to choose the correct medication.

Here is a part of my code:

```
 # first model
NoSide_df = df[df['side_effect'] == 0]
# Séparation des caractéristiques (X) et de la variable cible (y)
X = NoSide_df[["white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender"]]
y = NoSide_df['medication']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
modelNoSide = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
modelNoSide.fit(X_train, y_train)

# second model
Side_df = df[df['side_effect'] == 1]
# Séparation des caractéristiques (X) et de la variable cible (y)
X = Side_df[["white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender"]]
y = Side_df['medication']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
modelNoSide = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
modelSide.fit(X_train, y_train)

# prediction for first model
prediction_medicamentNoside = modelNoSide.predict(new_data)
proba_prediction_medicamentNoside = modelNoSide.predict_proba(new_data)
probability_class_NOSide0 = proba_prediction_medicamentNoside[0, 0]  
probability_class_NoSide1 = proba_prediction_medicamentNoside[0, 1]
# prediction for second model
prediction_medicamentSide = modelSide.predict(new_data)
proba_prediction_medicamentSide = modelSide.predict_proba(new_data)
probability_class_Side0 = proba_prediction_medicamentSide[0, 0] 
probability_class_Side1 = proba_prediction_medicamentSide[0, 1]  

#prediction combined
# Probabilités maximales des deux modèles
max_probability_modelNoSide = max(probability_class_NOSide0, probability_class_NoSide1)
min_probability_modelSide = min(probability_class_Side0, probability_class_Side1)

# Moyenne des probabilités maximales
average_max_probability = (max_probability_modelNoSide + min_probability_modelSide) / 2.0

if probability_class_NOSide0 > probability_class_NoSide1:
    # Affichage de la moyenne des probabilités maximales
    print("medicament = 0 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", average_max_probability,"\n",
         "medicament = 1 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", 1-average_max_probability,)
else: 
    print("medicament = 1 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", average_max_probability,"\n",
         "medicament = 0 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", 1-average_max_probability,)
```

Could you please help me with this approach or suggest a better way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want help on the statistics rather than programming, have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No i didn't see stats.stackexchange.com. For me, it sounds like a logic porblem.
And i tougth that a porblem like that should be very common.

Comment: Sounds like a stats problem to me!  The details I'd be interested in (summary stats of your data by column along with data types, e.g. which are binary, discrete or continuous values) are would help with suggesting an appropriate statistical/machine learning model.

Comment: in fact, for the moment I'm working with a randomly generated database just to come up with the idea.
"white_blood_cells," "age," "weight, these are continuous variables and "sex" is discrete. The real database I'm going to use contains dozens of variables with a lot of missing values ​​that I won't be able to fill in. C This is why I plan to use histgradientboostingclassifier. It will be for a friend's medical thesis.

Comment: Medication and side effects seem less useful from a medical point of view, not sure how these aren't categorical or even one-hot encoded.  Then I think it would make sense be be learning which medications could be prescribed to minimize side effects.  Dose and severity might also make sense to include when you get something working.  This is all very applied statistics commentary though

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't split data into side effects vs not.  1000 people having side effects means very different things when it's been prescribed to 1500 people vs a million.

Comment: You should be able to do much better than randomly making up data, side effect information should be published e.g. https://bnf.nice.org.uk/drugs/loratadine/#side-effects with the categories having well defined rates https://bnf.nice.org.uk/medicines-guidance/adverse-reactions-to-drugs/#side-effects-in-the-bnf

Comment: thank you Sam for your comment, but as I already explained, this is a random database that I created to make it easier to find how to solve the problem. Thank you anyway for your time, I will look at the statisticians as you advised me

Comment: I've spent a a few years as an applied statistician (i.e. applying existing methods to novel situations) in various medical fields (e.g. infectious diseases and genomics) hence my comments are from having worked with these sorts of problems before.